# Code doesn't run on my system but runs in another system

Tags: differential-equations

I have an issue with Mathematica. I have some code and its answer. When I run the code on my system, it doesn't work.

The person who wrote the code believes that is correct, and I agree. I tried to run this code in the same version of Mathematica that she has used (V7) and got no answer again. Also, I tested it on other systems, but it did not work there either.

Please, if you have an idea on this problem, let me to know.

```
h = h0*Sqrt[(om0*a^-3) + (β*op0*(1/(a + k)^λ)*Exp[-k*λ/(k + a)])];
pp = 
  DSolve[
    ϕ'[a] == -Sqrt[(1/3 a^2 A E^(-((k λ)/(a + k))) (a + k)^(-2 - λ) λ)/((a^2)*h^2)], 
    ϕ[a], a];
Simplify[pp]
```

[image]

Comment: With version 12 and on my Mac, I get the same answer as shown as "My answer". This answer can be verified by substitution into the differential equation. After manually entering the result shown as "Her answer" I was unable to verify it by substitution into the differential equation.

Comment: Evaluating your `DSolve` expression with V11.3 gave me "My answer" as well. I have less confidence in a V7 solution than in V11.3 or later one..

Comment: You are wrong to say the code doesn't run on your system. It runs there an you get an answer. You just don't like it.

Comment: Dear @BobHanlon thanks for your reply and time.

Comment: Dear @m_goldberg thanks for your answer. And you are right I get an answer but it isn't suitable for me. Actually the answer must be in term of incomplete Gamma function.